# An exercise to show that CBC Chain is insecure

Tags: provable-security, cbc, security-definition, semantic-security

The CBC-Chain mode of operation is a CBC variant in which the IV that is used for
the very first message to be encrypted is randomly selected, whereas the IV used for
each subsequent encrypted message is the last block of ciphertext that was generated.
Show that CBC-Chain is insecure by constructing an efficient IND$-CPA adversary.

My Approach: Designing an adversary

Query $0^n$, get $C_1=E_k(IV)$.

Query $C_1$, get $C_2=E_k(0^n)$.

Now if we query $C_2||m_1||m_2||\dots$

Then encrypted text will be $C_1'||C_2||C_3'||\dots$ where $C_2=C_1'$

Hence CBC chain mode is insecure.

This is what I have tried, don't know if it's correct, any help with the answer will be truly appreciated.

Here the Adv is 1 in terms of IND-CPA, Can anyone write down the IND$-CPA with Adv equals 1.

Added:

Adversary $A^{\epsilon_k(LR(.,.,b))}$

$M_{0,1}\leftarrow 0^n; M_{1,1} \leftarrow 0^n$

$M_{0,2} \leftarrow 0^n; M_{1,2} \leftarrow 0^{n-1}1$

$<IV_1, C_1> \stackrel{$}{\leftarrow} \epsilon_k(LR(M_{0,1}, M_{1,1}, b))$

$<IV_2, C_2> \stackrel{$}{\leftarrow} \epsilon_k(LR(M_{0,2}, M_{1,2}, b))$

If $C_1=C_2$ then return 1 else return 0.

Comment: Isn't $C_1' = C_1$

Comment: Not necessarily.

Comment: I'm a bit confused, what is $C_1'$? Also if this is for an assignment, you probably want to clearly state what your adversary outputs when i.e. 0 or 1.

Comment: I suggest that you describe in detail the experiment that the adversary you are trying to build is interacting with. The adversary that you propose must fit that experiment, and I'm afraid that the currently proposed adversary does not, for failing to make guesses. In the IND-CPA game (without \$), the adversary repeatedly submits two plaintexts and tries to guess which got encrypted (decided at random). From what I get of IND\$-CPA, the adversary repeatedly submits one plaintext, and tries to guess if it got encrypted or if the query returned a random string (decided at random).

Comment: Also, it is better to define the CBC-chain with equations, too.

Comment: I think I am not being able to construct the adversary. Any help will be great.

Comment: Could you formally define the CBC-Chain? How the adversary is going to detect the chain used is not clear, since they will send two plaintexts and will get encryption of one!

Comment: This looks like the attack described here: https://nerdoholic.org/uploads/dergln/beast_part2/ssl_jun21.pdf.

Comment: Also as @fgrieu and others rightly stated. It will be helpful (for you) to precisely specify the encryption scheme. As in specify KGEN, ENCRYPT, DECRYPT functions with input and output behavior. Since this is related to CBC, the above functions will probably be similar to vanilla CBC, maybe you need to add some state to account for the "IV chaining".

Comment: The question has one intuition right: the adversary always submits encryption queries that consist of (or start with) the last block obtained as ciphertext, which causes something special to happen in CBC. What's missing is how the adversary tries to assert if what it gets back from the query is indicative that what was obtained as ciphertext is actually the result fo CBC encryption (and a quantitative evaluation of the advantage obtained by that method). How would you do that? Describe it, and the hardest part is done.

Comment: Here the Adv is 1 in terms of IND-CPA, Can anyone write down the IND$-CPA with Adv equals 1.

Adversary $A^{\epsilon_k(LR(.,.,b))}$

$M_{0,1}\leftarrow 0^n; M_{1,1} \leftarrow 0^n$

$M_{0,2} \leftarrow 0^n; M_{1,2} \leftarrow 0^{n-1}1$

$<IV_1, C_1> \stackrel{$}{\leftarrow} \epsilon_k(LR(M_{0,1}, M_{1,1}, b))$

$<IV_2, C_2> \stackrel{$}{\leftarrow} \epsilon_k(LR(M_{0,2}, M_{1,2}, b))$

If $C_1=C_2$ then return 1 else return 0.